# Does there exist a comprehensive compilation of Erdos's open problems?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview, open-problems, erdos

Fan Chung and Ron Graham's book *Erdos on Graphs: His Legacy of Unsolved Problems* (A. K. Peters, 1998) collects together all of Erdos's open problems in graph theory that they could find into a single volume, complete with bounties where applicable.  Of course Erdos posed many other open problems in combinatorics and number theory that do not appear in this book.  I once heard a rumor that some people were working on a project to publish a similar but more comprehensive book or series of books, covering *all* of Erdos's open problems, but I don't know if the rumor is true.  Does such a compilation exist?  If not, is there *anything* else like this besides Chung and Graham's book?

Comment: I've added the "Erdos" tag.

Comment: "I see no inconsistency, ergo it exists", said Jon Mathematically.

Comment: old usenet sci.math post jul 11 1992 by greg kuperberg archived by rusin: http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/93_back/prizes.erd

Comment: Tag open-problems-list  seems relevant

Comment: @AlexanderChervov : Good suggestion. I have added that tag.

Comment: Alexander Soifer has been for years threatening to publish a book which should give a comprehensive account of Erdős's open problems. The book was even listed briefly in Springer's catalogue but then it disappeared, probably because it is not ready yet. You may want to contact him.

Comment: @vzn Unfortunately that link doesn't seem to work any more, but fortunately, the Wayback Machine has saved a copy: [The Erdos kitty:  At least $9050 in prizes!](https://web.archive.org/web/20150316025100/https://math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/93_back/prizes.erd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recently, Thomas Bloom created a website dedicated exactly to this:

https://www.erdosproblems.com/

It currently lists 214 problems, both open and closed. They are all tagged and some problems carry additional information. The list still evolves and if a problem is missing you might want to contact Thomas directly.

Comment: Very nice! Although this list may not yet be complete, I think it is a better answer than the [answer I previously accepted](https://mathoverflow.net/a/27728), so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 21):

I would be most impressed if there existed such a list! The closest thing I've found is this [long list of references](http://www.emis.de/classics/Erdos/problems.htm) to papers Erdős published containing problems. I don't know if it is comprehensive, and it has some overlap with the content of Chung and Graham's book, but it at least contains the names of the Erdős papers cited in Guy's *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*.

Comment: Very nice!  I was not aware of this bibliography.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

Although not an answer to the original question, but let me mention that Erdos' papers up to 1989 are available [here.](http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/Erdos.html)

Answer (score 9):

This is not a direct answer to your (good!) question, but *[Research Problems in Discrete Geometry](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/geometry/book/978-0-387-23815-9)* by Brass, Moser, and Pach (Springer 2005) cites Erdős more than 100 times.

Answer (score 8):

For graph theory problems, I find this the most comprehensive resource: http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/

Comment: This appears to be an online "living version" of the 1998 book by Ronald Graham and Fan Chung, mentioned by the OP. Good to know.