# improving known bounds for Pierce expansions; cash prize

Tags: nt.number-theory, algorithms, open-problems

Here's a problem that I thought of back in 1978 or so, and only a little progress has been made on it since then.  I still think about it from time to time, but probably not that many people have thought about it.  As I'm getting older, I now offer a cash prize for anyone who can make new progress.

The problem concerns the number of steps in an extremely simple algorithm.  Let $a, b$ be positive integers with $a > b$.  Set $b_0 = b$, and for $i \geq 1$ define $b_i = a \bmod b_{i-1}$.  Since in general $x \bmod y < y$, this means $b_0 > b_1 > \cdots$ and so eventually $b_n = 0$.  Define $P(a,b) = n$ in this case.  Thus, for example, $P(35,22) = 7$, since $b_0 = 22$, $b_1 = 35 \bmod 22 = 13$, $b_2 = 9$, $b_3 = 8$, $b_4 = 3$, $b_5 = 2$, $b_6 = 1$, $b_7 = 0$.  This looks superficially like the Euclidean algorithm for the gcd, but behaves quite differently.

Question:  how big is $P(a,b)$ as a function of $a$?  The upper bound $P(a,b) = O(a^{1/3})$ is known and the lower bound $P(a,b) > c \log a$ for infinitely many $a$ is also known.  (See, for example, http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/JTNB/JTNB_1991__3_1/JTNB_1991__3_1_43_0/JTNB_1991__3_1_43_0.pdf - my first and only paper with Erdos, and https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1996/21/cs-96-21.pdf .)

I offer US \$200 for any significant improvement to either the upper or lower bounds.  If I had to guess, I'd say probably $P(a,b) = O((\log a)^2)$.

One reason why this is interesting is because $P(a,b)$ is essentially the length of the "Pierce expansion" for $b/a$, which is an alternating series expansion of the form ${1 \over {x_1}} - {1 \over {x_1 x_2}} + {1 \over {x_1 x_2 x_3}} - \cdots$.

Comment: Here's something that might be worth at least $2: I'm seeing some vague similarities between this problem and the one's complexity problem.  Let S_r be the set of those a for which P(a,b) <= r for all b < a, and with equality for at least 1 b.  The sequence of S_r bears some resemblance to sequence of T_r, the set of numbers with one complexity = r (see arxiv:1404.2183 by de Reyna and van de Lune for a recent treatment).  In particular, max S_r = 2,6,24,72,240,720,2880,6720,9240 for r from 1 through 9.  Gerhard "But Wait!  There is More!" Paseman, 2014.04.23

Comment: Min S_r is 1,3,5,13,11,19,35,47,53,95, 103,179,251,299,503,743,1019,1319,1439,2939, 3359,3959,6619,5387,5879, a mostly monotonic sequence for r from 1 to 26, with several entries of high integer complexity.  I would set this problem in front of those working on integer complexity and see what they think.  (Of course, these are results from a quickly written and possibly error prone program.  The line of attack should still be worth pursuing.)  Gerhard "Is It Coincidence, Or Murder?!?" Paseman, 2014.04.23

Comment: Also, for each a in S_r, I suspect the smallest b for which P(a,b)=r satisfies  a < 2b < a + O(log^2 a), but I have not verified this yet.  Gerhard "Just Adding My Two Cents" Paseman, 2014.04.23

Comment: Now that I spent minutes in the lab, I've spent seconds reading the 1996 pdf which reproduces the results in the comments above, except that max S_9 is 20160, and my table for min S_r measures something slightly different.  I imagine the $2 connection has already been explored.  Gerhard "Decades Late, Two Dollars Short" Paseman, 2014.04.23

Comment: Have you tried the chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: If the sequence $b_i$ were to decay geometrically, i. e if we had roughly $b_{(i+1)}=b_{i}*b/a$, you would get something like $P(a,b)$ roughly equal to $\log b/(\log a-\log b)$. I don't know if this helps.

Comment: The decay of the $b_i$ is quite eccentric.  For fixed $b$ and $a$ large it is easy to understand, but otherwise not so easy.

Comment: Just a historical remark - Pierce expansion was also considered by [Ostrogradsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mikhail_Ostrogradsky) (1801-1862), along with another kind of expansion. This was discovered in 1950s in Ostrogradsky's handwritten notes by E. Ya. Remez, who published the details in the paper [On series with alternating sign which may be connected with two algorithms of M. V. Ostrogradskii for the approximation of irrational numbers](http://mi.mathnet.ru/eng/umn6883) (in Russian).

Comment: Zachary Chase and Mayank Pandey have recently posted a preprint to the arXiv, https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.08374 , where they improve the upper bound from 1/3 to 1/3-2/177.

Answer (score 9):

Very nice question! This is a (long) comment, not an answer

I found a heuristic suggesting the lower bound is sharp, and wonder if you have some reason to doubt it. The model is that given $n$ and $a_k$, $a_{k+1}$ is uniformly chosen from the set $\{0,\ldots,a_k-1\}$. Alternatively, $a_{k+1}=\lfloor Ua_k\rfloor$, where $U$ is a uniform random variable. So you're asking starting from somewhere in the range 1 to $a$, how many $U$'s do you have to multiply before you get 0 (integer part). You can check quickly that the probability you don't get 0 after multiplying $100\log a$ terms is $O(a^{-K})$ for some reasonably large power.

So even accounting for the a different values of $b$, the probability that any of them lead to a chain of length 100$\log a$, is $O(a^{1-K})$. Since this is summable, by Borel-Cantelli, there is $a_0$ such that for all $a\ge a_0$, there's no chain of length $100\log a$.

Comment: Yes, this is a good heuristic.  I used a version of it to prove some (pretty easy) theorems about the "metric" version of the algorithm, where you start with a real number $x \in (0,1)$ and you repeatedly apply the operation $1 \bmod {}$ to it.  See http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/24-1/shallit.pdf .  But I don't know how to convert these metric ideas to a proof in the integer case.  The available numerical evidence suggests a growth rate very slightly greater than $\log a$, but the available evidence is admittedly rather weak.