# Short research articles

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, cv.complex-variables, special-functions

I am a masters student. I am  interested in **short articles** which have counter examples and very few references. I want to write a short and interesting article.

**For example**; One of the best known shortest and best academic paper articles I read is *Counterexample to Euler's Conjecture on Sums of  Like Powers*  by L. J. Lander and T. R. Parkin (Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. **72** (1966) p 1079, doi:[10.1090/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9904-1966-11654-3)).
It has only one reference. It's really fascinating.

Is there any short articles in Mathematics and especially **in Analysis/Complex Analysis**? I am  also looking at **Counterexamples books** for learning something and I searched open problems in Wikipedia and looked at undiscovered, newly valued and current topics.

So can you share these type of articles you read? I am curious about a good and interesting **short article topic**. What do you recommend to me about it? You can also give some references.** Thanks for your ideas and answers.**

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/q/7330/12357

Comment: it's very nice. thank you very much.

Comment: There is a journal called Examples and Counterexamples, https://www.journals.elsevier.com/examples-and-counterexamples/ (I haven't seen it, so I can't do better than to refer you to the website)

Comment: William Chen, Counterexamples to Knaster's conjecture, Topology Vol. 37. No. 2, pp. 401-405, 1998.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks a lot:) the link is very useful. i will research journal and article.

Comment: On a lighter note: [The shortest papers ever published](https://paperpile.com/blog/shortest-papers/).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[a bit too long for a comment]

I understand from the question that the aim is to find a research project based on the search for a counterexample. By construction, this will mean showing that some existing paper in the literature is mistaken. That is typically not a productive way to start a project in a new field, simply because (a) if the author of that paper is clueless then there is not much gained in showing them wrong by finding a counterexample,$^\ast$ while (b) if the author is an expert you are facing an uphill battle if you are just entering a field.

Typically, a more productive way to enter a field is to try to generalize/extend work of others, basically by exploring corners of the field they left untouched (or didn't bother to explore). You may find that this leads you to uncover an error/oversight in the paper you started from, but that would then be a byproduct of your research and not the primary motivation.

<sub>$^\ast$ many questions here on MathOverflow can be readily dismissed by finding a counterexample, but that rarely becomes something worthy of a publication</sub>

Comment: it's perfect comment and  very nice perspective. i see it:)

Comment: Finding a counterexample to a conjecture might not be hard. James Davis's [counterexample](https://mathoverflow.net/q/271801) to Conway's climb-to-a-prime conjecture comes to mind (although I don't think he got a formal publication out of it).

Comment: @TimothyChow: As that example shows, there exist significant conjectures for which finding a counterexample isn’t hard.  But *finding* such conjectures is hard.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine : I may be misreading Carlo Beenakker's answer, but it sounded like he was talking about counterexamples to a published *theorem* and I was trying to say that it's easier to find counterexamples to a published *conjecture*. I would not normally describe a person who conjectures something that turns out to be false as "clueless" or even "mistaken."

Comment: "By construction, this will mean showing that some existing paper in the literature is mistaken." That's not at all what a counterexample is! There are many papers whose main contribution is an ingenious counterexample to a well-known published conjecture or folklore question. These can be quite lengthy and occasionally highly technical, and it is uncommon that they only have 1 or 2 references like the OP suggests.

Answer (score 8):

For counterexamples in analysis, a good start would be "Counterexamples in Analysis" by Gelbaum and Olmsted, there's even a Dover edition.

Comment: Thank you:) I will research its details.

Comment: Also Theorems and Counterexamples in Mathematics by the same authors, https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387973425