# Primality test similar to the AKS test

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, algorithms

Let us define polynomials $P_n^{(a)}(x)$ as follows :

> $P_n^{(a)}(x)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\cdot\left(\left(x-\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n+\left(x+\sqrt{x^2+a}\right)^n\right)$

We can define these polynomials by the recurrence relation also :

$P_0^{(a)}(x)=1$

$P_1^{(a)}(x)=x$

$P_{n+1}^{(a)}(x)=2xP_n^{(a)}(x)+aP_{n-1}^{(a)}(x)$

Note that $T_n(x)=P_n^{(-1)}(x)$ , where $T_n(x)$ is Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind .

Next , let us formulate the following claim :

> Let $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ , $n \in \mathbb{N}$ , $n \ge 3$ and $\operatorname{gcd}(a,n)=1$ . Then $n$ is prime if and only if $P_n^{(a)}(x) \equiv x^n \pmod{n}$ .

You can run this test [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxNjEEKwjAQRfeFXqKrTJNF0y7HOYJXEFqtGJpMhjRiRLy7QRDc_M9_PD7TZLFtZppqSvRPjsHNXgWzAL1kIItiqeBGIz5uzq9qO1AwQmNferF66WXAqsnXE9y0BkxrvidWAvhuG3dVx3hRf99sZjAMROXERpLjrLpaYe3gN88xSNxdrgjwAwY5M28=&lang=gp) .

The AKS test goes like this :

> Input : integer $n>1$
>
> 1. If $n=a^b$ for $a \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b>1$ , output composite .
> 2. Find the smallest $r$ such that $\operatorname{ord}_r{n}>(\log_2n)^2$ .
> 3. If $1 < \operatorname{gcd}(a,n) <n$ for some $a \le r$ , output composite .
> 4. If $n \le r$ , output prime .
> 5. For $a=1$ to $ \left\lfloor \sqrt{\varphi(r)} \log_2(n) \right\rfloor$ do
>
>    if $(x+a)^n \not\equiv x^n+a \pmod {x^r-1,n}$ , output composite .
> 6. Output prime .

**Question .** Under assumption that a claim given above is correct can we change step 5 into :

> For $a=1$ to $ \left\lfloor \sqrt{\varphi(r)} \log_2(n) \right\rfloor$ do
>
> if $P_n^{(a)}(x) \not\equiv x^n \pmod {x^r-1,n}$ , output composite .

and still have a correct algorithm ?

You can run this modified version [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJx1kEFuwyAQRfc5BclqcKZqoEvCEXoCy5ZojBNcG1zsKrSLnr1D60ZplbIZ0P_6vPleC_kg1CoNZoaIHg1nmpWySMiMYgLZrioeQwMCUx3vBF8enquVa2ENbhrD2UbwXOsdxzE6P8PmEIYxTG62G45RS3U-ud6S-3howGMkryBhu-WL8u5DbCglh2ed7zX04Uip93lIzmuZ_f8HceX0TrUhgtESB-fzNsSLRPmdajLhDUDlKPcpWvOcQ1pw2UbT73X8sdMY8i7d5Q-BbR_oNr3EGexrb-N4ckDkxR9wjsMbpJFaveq49kWZUFQfXz-uSS9lxbRmGTVdOl46r_2tYlX3m7u7Wm_hzUd9Av44kR8=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) .

Comment: Could you estimate whether this gives any improvement over the AKS? Or, if your aim is different, describe it? Understand me correctly please, this is certainly very intriguing, I would just like to know what you are up to.

Comment: Also in step 2, if $r$ and $n$ are not coprime, cannot you just finish and declare $n$ composite?

Comment: How this is different from https://mathoverflow.net/q/286304 ?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე I am just curious to know whether this modified algorithm is correct . I have fixed step 2.....thanks...

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that the claim can hardly be tested for large $n$ as it required computing polynomials of degree $n$.

At the same time, verifying it for any particular value of $x$ won't be sufficient. For example, when $a=-1$, such verification will fail to identify elements of [OEIS A299799](https://oeis.org/A299799) as composite (unless one find a divisor of $n$). For $n$ from this sequence, we have $$T_n(b)\equiv b\equiv b^n\pmod{n}$$ for any integer $b$ coprime to $n$. Here, the former congruence is the property of Chebyshev pseudoprimes, while the latter one is the property of Carmichael numbers, and elements of A299799 are both.