# How to put a monetary incentive on an open research problem?

Tags: soft-question, open-problems, online-resources, research

Since the old days, many famous mathematicians have been attaching monetary rewards to problems. I would like to put monetary bounties on some research mathematics problems. Some of those problems might be solved or partially solved by a hard-working college graduate in pure math.

The ideal platform to put these questions would be a website like MathOverflow: high visibility, acceptable ranking algorithm, and little distractions (Ads). However, I have yet to find a single forum for posting these kind of questions, let alone being "ideal". I am not sure if we could attach a monetary incentive in the body of the question here on this site.

I could also hire a research assistant but I am not sure if I could attract a high quality one as I am not a tenure-track faculty at a renowned institute.

Another alternative will be freelancing websites. However, no one put research math questions there: those sites are full of coding problems and homework problems.

And of course, we could publish an advertisement just like what have done by those famous mathematicians. However, with little reputation, we are unlikely to attract enough attention.

What resources do we have for posting the open research problems?

Comment: If you believe an other SE is more suitable for this problem, please let me know and I will move it asap.

Comment: Start a blog...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open problems with monetary rewards](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66084/open-problems-with-monetary-rewards)

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Are you suggesting that I could use that thread to post my questions?

Comment: How much money are you willing to spend on this enterprise?

Comment: I think this depends on how well known you are, for example Erdos was famous in the community so I presume word just got round when he put up a ''bounty'' on some problem he wanted to see solved.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I am not rich so $100-10k for each problem depending on difficulty. Not enough to make a headline, though.

Comment: @HollisWilliams Yes of course. I am far far from famous.

Comment: $10,000 on one single problem?

Comment: I suggest you try asking your question at MO main, and see what happens. You might get an answer for free!

Comment: @ToddTrimble One other SE site explicitly bans the attachment of monetary incentive with a question.

Comment: Some years back, an incident arose where it looked like some monetary incentive was in the offing, and it didn't seem the community was much in favor. I think it's not a bad idea just asking your research question at MO without mentioning money, and see what happens.