# List of problems that Erdős offered money for?

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, ho.history-overview, erdos

Is there a list somewhere of all the problems that Erdős offered cash awards for, including both solved and unsolved problems? One would think that the answer is yes, but so far I have had no luck finding such a list.

Greg Kuperberg compiled a partial list, which he posted in the [answer to another MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/a/66219), but I don't think it is complete; in particular, it seems that Kuperberg's list does not include the problem recently solved by Oliver Janzer ([Disproof of a conjecture of Erdős and Simonovits on the Turán number of graphs with minimum degree 3](https://arxiv.org/abs/2109.06110)), although it does include a related problem.
(Incidentally, Janzer's remarkable result is what prompted me to ask this question, since I was wondering if there were any other cases where Erdős offered more money for a counterexample than a proof and yet the conjecture was false.)

There is also a [related list on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_conjectures_by_Paul_Erd%C5%91s) as well as a [similar MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27716) that I asked a while ago,
but these don't quite answer my question (although Fan Chung and Ron Graham's book
*Erdős on Graphs: His Legacy of Unsolved Problems* presumably contains all the
graph-theoretic problems that Erdős offered money for).

Comment: [The Erdős problem page](https://www.math.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/All.html) lists 170 problems in graph theory, 20 of which have a cash prize.